# How To Sort Firebase Joined Query

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm New To firebase, i have a query

```
const posts = database.child('posts');
const user = database.child('user');

posts.orderByChild("id").on('child_added', snap => {
    let user_id = snap.val().user_id;

    let userRef = database.child('user/' + snap.val().user_id)
userRef.on('value', userSnap => {
        console.log(userSnap.val().name)
        let content = snap.val().content;
        let date_posted = snap.val().date_posted;
        let id = snap.val().id;
        let title = snap.val().title;
        let user_id = snap.val().user_id;
        let user_Name = userSnap.val().name;
        a.push({
            "id": id,
            "title": title,
            "date_posted": date_posted,
            "content": content,
            "user_Name": user_Name,
            "user_id": user_id
        })
    });

});
```

before entering UserRef Query, The posts are well sorted With The id,
however after the 2nd query, it's no longer sorted, How Can i make them sorted even after the 2nd query

this is the db structure
!:
[image: Posts]
[image: Posts]

i want the output to be like this

```
{
    id: 1,
    title: 'My First  Post',
    date_posted: '2018-05-02 19:40:02',
    content: 'This is my firstpost!',
    user_Name: 'Abdelrahman',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'My SecondPost',
    date_posted: '2018-05-02 19:41:02',
    content: 'This is my Second post!',
    user_Name: 'Abdelrahman',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'test Title',
    date_posted: '2021-01-06 08:48:01',
    content: 'test Content',
    user_Name: 'Abdelrahman',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    title: 'test Title2',
    date_posted: '2021-01-06 08:49:42',
    content: 'test Content2',
    user_Name: 'Abdelrahman',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    title: 'test 3',
    date_posted: '2021-01-06 08:54:14',
    content: 'COntent 3',
    user_Name: 'Abdelrahman',
    user_id: '8721da2c-0028-430f-a995-0d03c8abb393'
  }
```

but the output i see is not sorted at all

Comment: You can set the axios header in your main file and you can keep it in localstorage. So everytime you send a request axios will check if you have access token in your localstorage and you dont have to worry about auth anymore. Sorry if i got you wrong

Answer (score 0):

Usually you store the token as state in vuex. In your method you commit a mutation to set the token state, something like:

```
 this.$store.commit('SET_TOKEN', res.data)
```

In the store you will have

```
state: {
  token: '',
},
mutations: {
  SET_TOKEN(state, payload) {
  state.token = payload.token
}
```

This is just an example to be adjusted depending on response you get.

If you need to persist the state you should use also `vuex persisted state`